# Fix authentication cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication

**What I did**

The CakePHP version is 2.2.3

I used this part of the Cookbook to create my authentication: Link
After i was finished, i changed the fields to email and password (in AppController.php):

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User', 'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'))
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'twitter', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );
```

**What happened**

When i log in with my credentials, it redirects me to the loggedin page, even when the credentials aren't correct!

I hope someone can help me with the problem.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Login now works as far as i can see! But the logout doesnt work. It doesnt remove my session.

Comment: That’s the intended behavior: if your credentials aren’t correct then it’ll redirect you to the login page to rectify them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, i meant it redirects me to 'loginRedirect'. So to /twitter/index

Answer (score 1):

You are passing something to `$this->Auth->login($something)`. The code has changed since 1.x and anything passed to this method will cause the user to be logged in.

You should call `$this->Auth->login()` with no parameters

Comment: It is being called with no parameters in the UsersController:
`public function login(){
        $this->layout = 'login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            if ($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ongeldig email adres of wachtwoord. Probeer het AUB opnieuw'));
            }
        }
    }`